# Can I mount zfs dataset to another mointpoint?

Tags: zfs

I am using ZFSBootMenu for multi-zroot.

```
zpRoot/LINUX/Artix/System                 mountpoint                   /
zpRoot/LINUX/eos/SysClone1                mountpoint                   /                    
zpRoot/LINUX/eos/System                   mountpoint                   /
```

While boot into `zpRoot/LINUX/eos/SysClone1`, I want to read files from other dataset like `zpRoot/LINUX/eos/System`. The common way is to modify mountpoint and then mount, but I usually forget to restore mountpoint to `/`.

I tried `zfs mount -o mountpoint=/mnt/1 zpRoot/LINUX/eos/System` and `zfs mount -o altroot=/mnt/1 zpRoot/LINUX/eos/System`, but neither works.

How can I change mountpoint in memory without commit it to the disk ?

Answer (score 1):

I run a lot of ZFS on FreeBSD, but very little on Linux.  It looks like my Ubuntu system can't do this **without** setting `mountpoint=legacy`:

```
# zfs list -o name,canmount,mounted,mountpoint pool/test 
NAME       CANMOUNT  MOUNTED  MOUNTPOINT
pool/test        on       no  /home/research/test
# mount -t zfs pool/test /mnt
filesystem 'pool/test' cannot be mounted using 'mount'.
Use 'zfs set mountpoint=legacy' or 'zfs mount pool/test'.
See zfs(8) for more information.
```

On FreeBSD, it's easy to do, with `mount -t zfs <dataset> <temp mountpoint>`:

```
# zfs list -o name,canmount,mounted,mountpoint jimsdesk/home/test
NAME                CANMOUNT  MOUNTED  MOUNTPOINT
jimsdesk/home/test  on        no       /home/test
# mount -t zfs jimsdesk/home/test /mnt
# zfs mount | grep home
jimsdesk/home                   /home
jimsdesk/home/test              /mnt
```